# hello i am getting this error The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match

Tags: tensorflow-lite, bytebuffer

i am trying to develop my first android application using a tensorLite model but i keep on getting the error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match. when i run the code below

```
    predict.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            var resized: Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 260, 260,true)
            val model = Master.newInstance(this)

// Creates inputs for reference.
            val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 260, 260, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)

            var tbuffer = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resized)
            var byteBuffer = tbuffer.buffer

            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
            val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
            val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

            var max = getMax(outputFeature0.floatArray)

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
            tv.setText(townlist[max])

            model.close()
        })


}[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: When you have that specific type of error, is mostly because of a certain input not being considered. Could you please, the full error log?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i run the app it keeps on crashing an the error displayed is ;FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.maize, PID: 28975 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.